# не передаются данные в input через .innerText

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь передать данные в input:

```
<input  id="result" type="text" readonly="">
```

но на сайте ниче не показывается , пробовал result с другими тегами , например span , p все отлично работает, но с input никак не хочет работать, в чем проблема ?

```
 generate.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const length = lengthEl.value;
        const hasLower = lowercaseEl.checked;
        const hasUpper = uppercaseEl.checked;
        const hasNumber = numbersEl.checked;
        const hasSymbol = symbolsEl.checked;
        
        resultEl.innerText = generatePassword(hasLower, hasUpper, hasNumber, hasSymbol, length);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

```
resultEl.value = generatePassword(...
         ^^^^^
```